# Delete the existing content/data when bootstrap modal is closed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using bootstrap 3 modal to generate confirm dialog box before someone deletes a post. Currently what I am doing is grab the href values from the delete link and display it when delete(confirm) is clicked. I will use that link to send ajax request to server later.
Here is the simplified code.

```
// when modals shown
$('#confirm-delete').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var url = $(e.relatedTarget).data('href');

    $('button.delete').click(function(){
        alert(url);
    });
});

// when modals closed
$('#confirm-delete').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
   $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

However, when the dialog box is closed and opened second time it remembers the content(href values) from first click event.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to destroy the bootstrap modal window completely after closing it , to not restore everything when open it again .

```
$('#modal').on('hidden', function(){
$(this).data('modal', null);
```

});

if is bootstrap 3 you can use:

```
$("#modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
});
```

Comment: This is not deleting also <script> inside the modal