# Bootstraps Modal Popup not deleting displayed content when closed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Am displaying dynamic content from php server side on a Bootstraps 3 Modal view. when I display the first dynamic content and close the modal. the displayed data is not deleted.

If I click on the second the second modal button. I will still be seeing the previous displayed data along the the new content for dynamic data 2.

Each time modal button is clicked, it keeps on appending new content in the modal.

I need to delete all displayed dynamic content each time modal button is closed

I have tried solution here: [Delete the existing content/data when bootstrap modal is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211975/delete-the-existing-content-data-when-bootstrap-modal-is-closed)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal_video").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
  });
});
</script>
```

Below is the entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
    });
  });
  </script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myModalink_video").click(function(){

      var rec_uid = $(this).attr("id");
      $('#loader_video').fadeIn(400).html('<span class="alerts alert-info"><img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle"> Please Wait,Video is Loading.....</span>');

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'video.php',
        data: { rec_uid: rec_uid},
        success: function (data) {
          $('#loader_video').hide();
          $('#alertbox_video').fadeIn('slow').prepend(data);
        }
      });
    })
  });
  </script>

  <button id="89" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_video" class="btn btn-default myModalink_video">View Youtube Videos 1</button><br>
  <button id="90" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_video" class="btn btn-default myModalink_video">View Youtube Videos 2</button><br>

  <div  class="modal fade" id="myModal_video" role="dialog">
    <div  class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div  class="modal-content">
        <div style="background:#3B5998;color:white" class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" style="color:white">Close</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Hi Welcome</h4>
        </div>
        <div  class="modal-body">
          <!--display dynamic content Starts-->

          <h3>Propertises video</h3>

          <div id="loader_video"></div>
          <div id="alertbox_video"></div>

          <!-- Ends-->
        </div>
        <div style="20%" class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel/Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**video.php**

```
<?php
$rec_uid = $_POST['rec_uid'];
?>

<?php
if($rec_uid =='89'){
  ?>
  Video 1:<br>
  <iframe id="yVideo" width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hiHpzhyG6x4"></iframe>
  <?php
}
?>

<?php
if($rec_uid =='90'){
  ?>
  Video 2: <br>
  <iframe id="yVideo" width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xv6l1vOUZTg"></iframe>
  <?php
}
?>

<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ajax request is prepending content in `$('#alertbox_video')`.

So if you want to remove that content on close, I suggest you to use the [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal_video").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#alertbox_video').empty();
  });
});
```